# Where do I find the SYSTEM VALUE defaults? magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration, magento-2.1

I want to change the url rewrite area a bit - and I thought I would ask this question that has been bugging me for a bit:

Where are the defaults set? For example for url rewrites, I have to uncheck "Use system value" to change the behaviour. Where can I change this "SYSTEM VALUE"?

```
Use Categories Path for Product URLs                    Yes/No  [x] Use system value     
Create Permanent Redirect for URLs if URL Key Changed   Yes/No  [x] Use system value
```

Comment: Quite confuse, can you provide more information.

Comment: In the menu STores COnfig SEO  you can set up url rewrites. If I do not uncheck system value, it takes system value as the default. Where are these "System Values" ? Are system values (defaults) in some code? Or are they in some other menu where I lay out the defaults for this whole installation? Like email users is a global setup, taxes, currency etc - is a background default set up in some menus..

Comment: Oh boy Oh boy, a question about my idea and my implementation in M2 config. I'm filled with excitement.

Answer (score 24):

The system values are the default values each module can define in its config.xml. These are values that you can not change, the checkbox is something like "reset to manufacturers settings".

This also means that there should not be any reason to change the "system values". Changing global configuration (i.e. unchecking "use system value") sets the value system wide and the "system value" will not be used anywhere.

Comment: Hi, So we can only change these values in the xml files?

Comment: @jackyboi exactly